# Training Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to train tesseract to recognize some images but the manual isn't clear, do you know of any simple and straight forward guide for training tesseract?

Thank you.

Comment: Tesseract is not usual program, it requires good programming skills to configure it.

Comment: There is a training script provided at http://lib.psnc.pl/Content/358/PSNC_Tesseract-FineReader-report.pdf. Search in the document for train.sh

Comment: I suggest you yo install this program, it has a gui interface letting you train your own dataset http://sunnypage.ge/en/